# How to make Node.js wait for response from a large request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, multipartform-data

I am posting a large number of files that can take potentially minutes to upload. I using a multi-part form to post the files and then waiting for a response from the POST, but this can take several minutes.

How do I make Node/Express wait for this response? As of now, it seems like the request is "timing out" and Node or the browser is re-POSTing the files because it is taking so long. I can see this because my middleware functions are being called multiple times for requests that take too long.

Is there a library to make Node not timeout? Should I be attempting to POST these files in a different fashion? Thanks

```
var mid = function(req,res,next) {
  console.log('Called');
  next();
};

app.post('/api/GROBID', mid, authenticate, PDFupload.return_GROBID, PDFupload.post_doc, function(req, res) {
  if (res.locals.body == 400) res.send(400);
  /*if (process.env.TEST_ENV == 'unit-testing') {
    res.send(res.locals.body);
  }*/
  res.render('uploads', {files : res.locals.body});
});
```

Edit: This mid middleware (used as an example) is being called twice. This means the route is being posted to twice. How do I make sure this does not happen?

Comment: Have you tried a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

Comment: @jsrbn erm... that makes no sense. A promise won't help with express or nginx or whatever is timing out the request.

Comment: Without seeing any code I can just give suggestions of what may help @KevinB

Comment: Yeah. As per @jsrbn Promise does the trick.

Comment: There is no magic in Promise -- show some code and an example of what is not working so we can reproduce your problem and suggest solutions

Comment: Use [connect-timeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-timeout) middleware, but first you should know why the browser reposting files multiple times

Comment: I don't think Promise does the trick, check my edit to the main post

Comment: I tried connect-timeout, yet it still doesn't work

Comment: Seeing the middleware run twice makes me think you may have a very common client-side mistake where you aren't blocking the default form post.  What happens if this is the case is that your client-side Javascript post runs and then the browser issues a default form submission resulting in a second post received on your server.  We'd have to see how the post is configured in your client to know if this is actually what is happening.

Comment: Note- this only happens when the request takes longer than about two minutes. Shorter uploads have been working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

## Is there a library to make Node not timeout?

Express sits on top of [Node.js' built-in HTTP server](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html). By default, the timeout is 2 minutes. You can modify its default timeout as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>');
});

var server = app.listen(port);
server.timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10; // 10 minutes
```

## Should I be attempting to POST these files in a different fashion?

Yes, you can use [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.

And with Multer, you don't have to worry about the timeout anymore. Event the upload time is longer than the timeout, say 2 minutes by default, Express just won't timeout.

Here is the sample code:

#### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/your/path/to/store/uploaded/files/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // Keep original file names
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

// files is the name of the input html element
// 12 is the maximum number of files to upload
app.post('/upload', upload.array('files', 12), async (req, res) => {
  res.send('File uploaded!');
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

#### index.html

```
<html>

<body>
  <form ref='uploadForm' id='uploadForm' 
    action='http://localhost:3000/upload' 
    method='post' 
    encType="multipart/form-data">

    <input type='file' name='files' multiple/>

    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now try starting the web server:

```
node app.js
```

Then open your browser and go to http://localhost:3000

You can now upload a number of big files, which you can find later on in folder /your/path/to/store/uploaded/files/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try out multer!